# Scrapping website with Selenium 4.0 - python - by class name with spaces

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using python and Selenium 4.0 to scrape a web https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen:
I am trying to click an element so it goes to the next page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g27FD.png)

The button has the same class name as the numbers: `vtex-button__label flex items-center justify-center h-100 ph5`  with spaces in between. I tried using dots instead of spaces and each class seperately. Then I moved to the element inside it. Without luck:

`svg_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "vtex-button__label flex.items-center.justify-center.h-100.ph5"))).click()`

Comment: have you tried replacing spaces with dots and prededing the first class name with a dot too. bascially start all class names with dots and no spaces

Answer (score 0):

In you case unique locator is last element from selector `.items-center button.bg-action-primary svg`.
So, the code that clicks next button is:

```py
next_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.items-center button.bg-action-primary svg')))
next_button[-1].click()
```

But in your case it would be easier just to get number of pages aand go one by one via urls like `https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen?page=2`,  where 2 is number of page. It would be more stable solution.

Comment: I cannot know the amount of pages of each category. And the option you put there did not work.
I am trying with:
`next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".items-center button.bg-action-primary svg")
next_button.click()`

Comment: This is the error: [Error](https://ibb.co/WymJWJP).

Comment: For me it exists. https://monosnap.com/file/kUTHoy0nwmMY7DSzLDwaDb84EdAZF4

Have you tried to use explicit wait as I suggested? 

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`

Comment: I can see it in inspect, but not get it in the code.

Comment: `almacen = 'https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen/d'
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(almacen)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=2)
primer_avanzar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'valtech-carrefourar-search-result-0-x-paginationButtonChangePage').click()`

This is the code and throws me an error [link](https://ibb.co/6J3GBRw) but when I look into the website the class name is correct: [link](https://ibb.co/N6Qj1vF)

Comment: Have you tried explicit wait?
driver.get("https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".valtech-carrefourar-search-result-0-x-paginationButtonChangePage")))
next_button.click()

Comment: [error](https://ibb.co/k33g0tF) I did tried, but still throws an error.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.maximize_window()` before waiting for element?
`